# How to delete folders whose name is less than ...?

Tags: bash, filesystems

On my server, I have a bunch of archived folder name after the date: `yyyy-mm-jj` This allows to easily sort the folders and find relevant data.

I would like to delete all archives done before a given data. With my folder naming, natural sort order is the same as regular sort so that I could rely on the usual bash construct:

```
if [ $foldername -lt "yyyy-mm-jj" ]; then
    rm -r $foldername
fi
```

Is there a more efficient way to do it ?

Comment: No, that seems like the absolute best way to do it.  Why, are you having any speed problems?

Comment: You can use find with -mtime to find old files/folders.

Comment: No speed problem. I'm only seeking for elegant constructions :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[ $foldername -lt "yyyy-mm-jj" ]` will always be false, because `-lt` is a numeric operator: the strings you're comparing aren't numbers, so they're both treated as 0. Use the `<` or `>` operator instead to compare strings (this is a ksh/bash/zsh feature). Note that there are only string operators, there is no `<=` or `>=`.

Wildcard expansion returns the matching names in lexicographic order. So to act on the oldest files, loop through the files and break out when you find a file that's too recent.

```
for dir in [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]; do
  if ! [[ $dir < $min_date_to_keep ]]; then break; fi
  rm -r "$dir"
done
```

Comment: +1 mostly because this also makes sure only correctly named folders are checked and there's less risk that a random folder that just happens to be lexicographically less than whatever target date is being used gets deleted (for example if for some error the script runs on the wrong directory).